# Why Review Snippet is not showing in Google SERP for my website result?

Tags: seo

On my Magento Website, I apply product schema markup in my website but
Why My Review Snippet is not showing in Google SERP for my website result? give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can add review code in json example as below:

{
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Product",
      ...
      "review": [{
        "@type": "Review",
        "reviewRating": {
          "@type": "Rating",
          "ratingValue": "5"
        },
        "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "John Doe"
        }
       },
      }
    }
}

If you want to more schema format then please refer below link:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/review-snippet

Comment: of course, I added all product schema code in my Magento website, and when I checked site:domain.com the product schema showed but when normally in google with keywords product schema does not show    that's the issue